# How dynamically align button in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, button, alignment, interface-builder

I have such layout with two buttons. When I click on `Button 1` it has to disappear and `Button 2` has to be moved to center of layout. How can I perform this properly?

[image]

Comment: What is your deployment target?

Comment: iOS10 I suppose

Comment: Consider using of *autolayout* or *UIStackView*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **StackView**. You don't have to think about any layout constraint.That is center aligned. When you hide something from stackView it will automatically get centered according to your need.

Comment: Try this link.It's a nice tutorial. https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with **StackView**.set StackView `center horizotal and vertical alignment` and also set in StackView `attributes inspector` set **alignment** center and **distribution** Equal centering. Set both button width fixed.